# Simplifying onclick jquery/JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simplify all .js functions on the site to improve page load speed and overall performance of my site. Managed to do most of it on my own, but got stack when started to minimize couple of functions that are mostly call backs and onclick functions called from the functions.js in the page head.

SO here is my question, how can I make one function out of the following 2 to make script shorter and without loosing any functionality, or if there any alternative way to make it all simpler than it currently is?

```
function user_dialog(dialog_content, download_button) {
    if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
        $("#dialog").attr("title", "Lets share it").html(dialog_content);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: false,
            width: 400,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Download": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location = download_button;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        window.location = download_button;
    }
}

function user_notice(link_source) {
    download_link = $(link_source).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/json.php",
        data: "action=reminder&thepath=" + download_link,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function() {
            window.location = download_link;
        },
        success: function(resp_dialog) {
            if (resp_dialog.status == 1) {
                user_dialog(resp_dialog.html, download_link);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Comment: if you want to improve page load speed, you should use a [JS minifier](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

Comment: This isn't much of an optimization... if you're looking for performance gains you need to look at other issues first. There's almost no benefit from shortening this code. combining these functions would probably result in more code.

Comment: @adamb thanks, really wise suggestion, I have just done it and managed to decrease the size of function.js from 1883kb down to 892kb without loosing any functionality at all. Great

Comment: Are you caching anything? My guess is not. Nobody does. Aggressive caching will be the single biggest performance gain you could possibly make.

Comment: @CoryDanielson, Aggressive caching is one of the first things I have done, so this was kind of an additional thing to minimize the load. Also for others, whom might also be interesting in reductions and improvements, use good CDN for your static content distribution, that helps and helps massively.

Comment: So why are you spending time compressing 2 javascript functions? There's got to be other things for you to do. Have you optimized your images as well? Are you using sprites for the images? You should probably be fighting to reduce the # of HTTP requests on the initial page load

Comment: @CoryDanielson Yup, all done, one thing that is left to do is to use correct CSS selectors and I am all done. in your opinion, page speed 94 and yslow 93, is it good, not so good, bad, really poor? with page load in 6 major regions 1.44s?

Comment: Yeah, that's really good. What kinds of issues are you still having? What is the URL for this site? I'm not sure what kinds of optimizations you could have left without looking at the page. If it's a singe page app, are you doing offscreen rendering of DOM updates? Building HTML in memory and pushing it to the DOM in 1 update is a huge win for speed and efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an action variable in your function vars, like us_action and un_action then use an if statement to say if is us_acion, perform this else if un_action do this

Comment: Good call, in your opinion, page speed 94 and yslow 93, is it good, not so good, bad, really poor?

Comment: lol, you have already been told by CoryDanielson that shortening this code would not provide any benefit. I was simply trying to give you an idea of how to shorten it, but unless you're dealing with loads of repetitive functions, shortening them will not give much optimization. If you are looking to optimize your code there are many other things to look at first other than this.